# Identity Server 4 Angular Electron App Authentication Example

Tags: angular, electron, identityserver4, appauth

I'm looking for a good example authenticating an Angular Electron app from an Identity Server 4 server.

I have been sucesfull using oidc-client to connect to my identity server with an angular web app. 
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

The same implementation does not work for my Angular Electron app and I realize I should be using a different client library.

Ive settled on using AppAuthJs with my Angular Electron app but cant find an example on how to implement this.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/googlesamples/appauth-js-electron-sample) is an example from the AppAuthJs library. I remember we used it as a starting point for implementing our Electron app authentication.

I also remember that when implementing it with your own Identity Server, the bes approach was to go for the `authorization_code` grant type. You use the sample to execute the first request (`setAuthorizationListener` method), from the response, you get the `response code`, and using it, and all the other data for your client (`client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uri`) you create the `access_token` request, which will lead you to the login page.

After that the flow is the same as in your other JS client, with the fact, that in this case you will have a `refresh token`, that you can use to renew your `access token`.

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what Ive been looking for!